# Multi-line buttons in HTML

Tags: html, button, internet-explorer-7, multiline

If the width of a button element isn't wide enough to contain the button text Firefox and Chrome give the button more height, IE (v7 at least) will just cut off. How can I make IE  expand the height to contain the text? Ideally just using CSS.

I've tried explicitly giving IE7 a height that makes the button bigger but it still just displays one line of cut off text.

```
<button style="width:40px;">Some really long text that is more than 20px</button>
```

In the real version I'm using the ButtonGroup YUI control so can't use `<input>`
elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have IE7 installed, but adding a `DIV` inside the button works in IE6:

```
<button style="width:40px;"><div style="height: 100%">Some really long text that is more than 20px</div></button>
```

[Example in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/FJtHT/)

Comment: That caused some issues with YUI buttons and firefox (my test case was fine) but I think they could be worked out. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I hope you can iron out the issues with YUI.

Answer (score -1):

CSS Only Button – Redux

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/06/css-button-redux/

Comment: That's not a <button>, it's an <a> wrapped in a <p>. Appearance and behavior are totally different.